# how to make col-md-3 at the right side align in html bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i want to make one div right align , but not able keep it in right side in row. how to make the value 172.21 at right side in the row.
screenshot[image: screenshot]

HTML:

```
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <h4>Status</h4>
                                        <input type="checkbox" disabled checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="outline-success" data-offstyle="outline-danger">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <h4>Max Demand  </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <h4>172.21</h4>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: The image doesn't reference the code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is text, just `"align-right"`

If there is block, in BS3:

Add `"pull-right"` to the element container

In BS4:

```
"float-right"
```

E.g. in BS4:

```
   <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <h4>Status</h4>
                                    <input type="checkbox" disabled checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="outline-success" data-offstyle="outline-danger">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <h4>Max Demand  </h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 float-right">
                                    <h4>172.21</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: i have checked with pull-right, its now working for me

Comment: @krishnamohan nice! I added also a version only for text. If my answer helps you please accept it as "correct" answer. Also will give you points to you. Thanks!

Comment: @RaeeshAlam its called float-right now. Code Updated

Comment: @Leando but also col-md-3 will not move to right due to cover 100% of columns width.

Answer (score 1):

You just need add class in last column like: **text-left text-md-right**. 
I hope below snippet will help you.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container border">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <h4>Status</h4>
   <input type="checkbox" disabled checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="outline-success" data-offstyle="outline-danger">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
   <h4>Max Demand  </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 text-left text-md-right">
   <h4 class="btn btn-warning">545</h4>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the text, add `text-right` class after `col-md-3`

and for the entire column, add `pull-right` class after `col-md-3` if you're using bootstrap-3

and for bootstrap-4 add `float-right` instead of `pull-right` class.